A morphism of sheaf spaces is continuous iff it is open iff it is a local homeomorphism
This question is a part of a result from Tennison's Sheaf theory (page 17, Lemma 3.5, (c)).
We call a pair $(E,p)$ a sheaf space over a topological space $X$ if $E$ is a topological space and the map $p:E\rightarrow X$ is a continuous local homeomoephism. Given two sheaf spaces $(E,p)$ and $(E^\prime,p^\prime)$ over the the same space $X$, we consider a map $\phi:E\rightarrow E^\prime$ satisfying $p^\prime\circ \phi=p$.
In Lemma 3.5 (c), it is claimed that the map $\phi$ is continuous iff it is open iff it is a local homeomorphism.
The only thing I could not show is that if $\phi$ is open then it is either continuous or a local homeomorphism.
The hint in the book suggests considering a neighborhood $U$ of a point $e$ in $E$ and following the previous arguments. I understood it as the following: we can take the open neighborhood $\phi(U)$ of $\phi (e)$ and somehow construct a local homeomorphism on some open neighborhood $U^\prime$ of $\phi(e)$ contained in $\phi(U)$ using $p^\prime$. But $U^\prime$ might not necessarily be $\phi (U_0)$ for some open subset $U_0\subset U$. So I can not use $p$ here to create a local homeomorphism on a smaller neighborhood.
On the other hand, the relation $p^\prime\circ \phi=p$ suggests that for any open set $U\subset E$ and any open set $V\subset X$, one can write $(p|_U)^{-1}(V)=(\phi|_U)^{-1}((p^\prime |_{\phi(U)})^{-1}(V))=(\phi|_U)^{-1}(\phi(U)\cap (p^\prime)^{-1}(V))$. If one can write any open set of $E^\prime$ as $(p^\prime) ^{-1}(V)$ there is still a way, but it seems too much to ask for.
Any idea will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Please let me know if you find any mistake.
Suppose that $\phi:E\rightarrow E^\prime$ is an open map, $e\in E,\phi(e)=e^\prime\in E^\prime$.
We find an open $U\subset E$ such that $e\in U$ and $p|_U :U\rightarrow p(U)$ is a homeomorphism. Note that $p|_U =p^\prime |_{\phi(U)} \circ \phi|_U$. Since $p|_U$ is injective and $\phi$ is an open map, $\phi|_U :U\rightarrow \phi(U)$ is a bijective open map. Writing $\psi|_{\phi(U)}=(\phi|_U)^{-1}$ we get $p^\prime |_{\phi(U)}=p|_U\circ \psi|_{\phi(U)}$, $p(e)=p^\prime (e^\prime)$, and $\psi|_{\phi(U)}$ is a continuous bijection.
For any open neighborhood $V\subset U$ of $e$, $p|_V :V\rightarrow p(V)$ is a homeomorphism. Find an open neighborhood $V^\prime \subset (\psi|_{\phi(U)})^{-1}(V)=\phi(V)$ such that $p^\prime|_{V^\prime}:V^\prime\rightarrow p^\prime(V^\prime)$ is a homeomorphism.
Consider $\psi|_{\phi(U)}:V^\prime\cap [(\psi|_{\phi(U)})^{-1}(V\cap p^{-1}(p^\prime(V^\prime)))]\rightarrow V\cap p^{-1}(p^\prime(V^\prime))$. It is continuous on  $N=V^\prime\cap [(\psi|_{\phi(U)})^{-1}(V\cap p^{-1}(p^\prime(V^\prime)))]$ and we can write $V\cap p^{-1}(p^\prime(V^\prime))=\psi(N)$. To see this, note that for any $z\in V\cap p^{-1}(p^\prime(V^\prime))$, we have $z\in V$ and we can find a $\mu\in V^\prime$ such that $p(z)=p^\prime (\mu)$. So we have $p(z)=p(\psi (\mu))$, $z\in V\subset U$, $\psi(\mu)\in V\subset U$ and $p|_U$ is a homeomorphism. Hence $z=\psi (\mu)\in V\cap p^{-1}(p^\prime(V^\prime))$ with $\mu\in V^\prime$. So $\mu\in V^\prime\cap [(\psi|_{\phi(U)})^{-1}(V\cap p^{-1}(p^\prime(V^\prime)))]$.
Now we show that the continuous bijection $\psi|_N :N\rightarrow \psi(N)$ is a homeomorphism. We have $\psi(N)$ as an open subset of $V$ where $p|_U$ is a homeomoerphism and $p^\prime|_N =p|_{\psi(N)}\circ \psi|_N$. We take a $z\in N$ and a net $z_\alpha\in N$ such that $\psi(z_\alpha)\rightarrow \psi(z)$ (which is taking place in $\psi(N)$). So $p(\psi(z_\alpha))\rightarrow p(\psi(z))$ in $p(\psi(N))$ which is taking place in $p^\prime (V^\prime)$. Recall $p(\psi(N))\subset p^\prime (V^\prime)$ and $N\subset V^\prime$. Since $p^\prime|_{V^\prime}$ is a homeomorphism, we conclude that $z_\alpha\rightarrow z$.
This concludes the proof.
